# Removing complete ASP.net 5 RC1 environment before moving to DOTNET Core RC2 from OSX

Tags: asp.net, macos

Recently, there is RC2 release for donet core tools. Previously, I have been using RC1 for asp.net 5. It was installed using .pkg file provided at get.asp.net.

Now, I am planning to try out dotnet core release. The instructions provided at get.asp.net ask to unistall the previous versions of dotnet core using [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh).

I have 2 questions here.

1. Is it required to remove the RC1 release (dnvm,dnx and dnu etc) before installing dotnet core?
2. If it is required to uninstall, what is preferred way of doing it (something like above script) without damaging the required/shared files?

Answer (score 1):

**Ad 1.** Yes. As you can read in [ASP.NET Core installation guide](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#debian):

> Before you start
>
> Remove all previous versions of .NET Core from your system.

**Ad 2.** In my case I just use Add/Remove programs, but it's Windows.

I have no experience with Linux, but you do not need DNX any more so no worries about required files - after a while you will install new RC2 with all required files ;)

Comment: I have installed RC2 without uninstalling RC1. Now, I want to uninstall RC1 but I can't see any RC1 stuff on Add/Remove program window? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I just read your question... If you have installed RC2, so why you want remove RC1 now, something not working for you ?

Comment: Where is the link telling you to uninstall it?  Can't find it.

Comment: @lkuasz - here is an example of where things can go sideways if you don't uninstall old ones - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980044/does-not-support-framework-netcoreapp-version-v1-0