# does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Getting blowout trying to create and run a asp.net core (.net core) blank or web template.

I've have vs2015 update3 and .net core 1.0.1 tools preview 2 installed.

After creation I receive Package Restore Failed in my solution manager.

Errors list has lots of NU1002 errors of ilk of  "The dependency System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.0.0 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0"

Output window has similar stuff.

Help....

[image]

[image]

NUGET.CONFIG
Does not exist in project directory.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

PROJECT.JSON

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the project.json?

Comment: And the nuget.config

Comment: added inline to main query.

Comment: That says you are calling some methods from namespace `System.Security.Principal.Windows` what is not supported in framework `.NETCoreApp`

Comment: I just did a File, New....  Nothing was changed.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2017/0530 - talked to PG.  VS2015 just isn't supporting .net core.  You can go vscode or vs2017.  Ouch.

Issue was I had older .net core / vs2015 tooling installed.  Installed newer tooling without uninstalling old stuff.

Went through programs and features, removed all dotnet core installs, reinstalled latest, and it works now...

Lotsa fun.

Comment: Can you please give exact steps to do this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this pain when upgrading from 1.0 to 1.1, but it also happened when I was tring to add several "supported" packages in 1.0. The issues you are experiencing are located in projects.json.

Here are three links that might help. Just to note, the gitlab project is mine and I am not promoting it. I am using it as demonstration code.

https://github.com/euclid47/UsgsAnalysis/blob/master/project.json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/

You can also try adding the debugType line in your projects.json build options section.

```
 "buildOptions": {
     "debugType": "portable",
     "emitEntryPoint": true
 }
```

Hopefully this will fix the problem. Let me know how it goes.